# css border on select table cells with :nth-child, :nth-of-type selector in chrome

Tags: css

I am attempting to place a top border on specific cells in a table row. I am doing so with the following css:

```
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td:nth-of-type(1),
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td:nth-of-type(3),
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td:nth-of-type(5)
{border-top:1px solid #d6d5d5; }
```

This css works great for the 3rd and 5th child, but for some reason unbeknownst to me, when I add a border to the first child, it spans across the entire table row. This only happens in the chrome browser.

What am I missing? I've tried every configuration I can think of.

You can view this strangeness live on my site:
http://www.yandasmusic.com/Guitars-s/1820.htm

Comment: Holy nested tables batman!

Comment: Agreed. Thanks Volusion...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because the table you're targeting is contained inside another table, with the same class name:

```
<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="10" class="v65-productDisplay"> 
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td> <!-- this td is also targeted -->
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" class="v65-productDisplay"> 
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <!-- ... -->
```

So, this rule:

```
table.v65-productDisplay > tbody > tr:nth-child(5n+1) > td:nth-of-type(1)
```

Is matching the `td` that is wrapping the second nested table, giving it the top border.

Comment: Wow. I would have never seen that. You're absolutely right. Thanks for saving me a headache.